# php: memory_get_usage(true) doesn't increase

Tags: php, memory

got a strange problem. I want to check memory usage of a function and use

```
    class test {
      public function __construct() {
        $start = memory_get_usage(1);
        runFunctionNeededToCheck();
        var_dump(memory_get_usage(1) - $start);
      }
    }
```

But it just returns 0, the mem usage doesn't increase, while I create in this functions dozens of arrays, objects and some db transactions. Without real_usage flag, I got some valuations greater than 0, but I need the memory usage of just this script/functions.

So do you have some ideas? Or do you know why the memory seems to persist?

thx in advance

**Edit**

I tried a bit and it seems that functions are not the problem, but if you run this code inside an object you come to my end... (sorry that I didn't mentioned it at first)

**Doh!-Effect**

All local vars are cleared at end of a function. thx!

Comment: I think the problem is, that functions have their own stacks and this stack is cleared once the function is done - So the memory usage will be the same or nearly the same as before.

Comment: Thx for your tip. I tried a bit and it seems that functions are not the problem, but if you run this code inside an object you come to my end...

Comment: this might help you more: http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the function you call will have cleared up after itself by the time the `var_dump()` command is called.

Try putting the same lines inside the function itself, that may shed some light on the matter.

```
function runFunctionNeededToCheck()
{
    $start = memory_get_usage(1);

    //do something here....//

    return (memory_get_usage(1) - $start);
}
$memUsage = runFunctionNeededToCheck();
echo $memUsage;
```

Of course, whether or not there is any difference in memory usage depends entirely on what the function does - to make sure it IS using more memory, try opening an image file or something so you know that the useage will be more than before.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm it seams to work:

```
<?php
class test {

    public function __construct() {
        $start = memory_get_usage(1);
        range(1, 100000);
        var_dump(array('start' => $start, 'end' => memory_get_usage(1), 'sub' => memory_get_usage(1) - $start));
    }
}

$v = new test();
```

results:

```
array(3) {
  ["start"]=>
  int(786432)
  ["end"]=>
  int(1048576)
  ["sub"]=>
  int(262144)
}
```

Maby your function do not create any new variables or clear them in the end?

Comment: Yeah... okay - that's logical... All local vars are cleared at end of a function. thx!